# Send collected Email as a new ticket/issue in Gitlab Servicedesk feature

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gitlab

I am looking into integrating Google Forms and GitLab Service Desk.
Basically my own webform for GitLab.

GitLab Service desk treats new issues by the sender of the email.

Right now my code sends out an email to **servicedeskgitlab@mydomain.com** but uses my email account hence I'm the one receiving all the updates of the ticket/issue in GitLab. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function _onFormSubmit(e) {
  var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getFormUrl();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(url);
  var response = form.getResponses().pop();

  var url = form.getPublishedUrl();
  var responseId = response.getId();
  //google sheet entry
  var department = e.values[5];
  var ticketsubject = e.values[3];
  var ticketsummary = e.values[9];
  var urgency = e.values[7];
  var name = e.values[1];

  // for random id
  var uid = createRandomUid(responseId);
  writeUidToSheet(uid);
  writeStatusToSheet();

  var title = "Thank you for contacting Employee Success";
  //  var lastItem = response.getItemResponses().pop();

  var useremail = response.getRespondentEmail();
  var email = "servicedeskgitlab@mydomain.com";

  var subject = " EMPLOYEE SUCCESS Channel " + uid;
  var DEPTsubject = "New " + department + " ticket submitted " + uid + " by " +
    name;
  var htmlBody =
    "<table style='width: 600px; margin: 10px auto; background: #dfe4ea;'><tr>" +
    "<td style='padding: 0px 20px;'>" +
    "<h2 style='text-align: center; letter-spacing: 0.1em; background: linear-gradient(60deg, #16a085, #1abc9c); color: #fff; padding: 10px;'>" +
    title + "</h2>" +
    "<p>TICKET#</p>" +
    "<div style='padding: 20px;border-radius: 20px; background: linear-gradient(60deg, #16a085, #1abc9c);'>" +
    "<div style='font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; color: #ecf0f1; text-align: center;'>Ticket Number</div>" +
    "<div style='font-size: 25px; color: #2c3e50; text-align: center;'>" + uid +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<p><a href='" + url +
    "' style='color: #16a085;'>Submit another ticket</a></p>" +

    "<p>Thanks,<br>Employee Success</p>" +
    "</td></tr></table>";
  var options = {
    htmlBody: htmlBody
  };

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", options);
}
```

I'm a beginner with Apps Script/JavaScript. Is there a way that we can use the collected email as a sender to the GitLab email? This way the user/form submitter gets GitLab's updates.

Comment: Please ignore the HTML and random UID.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Spoiler: The options are complex and require authorization of the email address related account user.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén just corrected and improved the question.

Comment: Please don't include tags on question titles. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: I don't see any brief description of the search/research efforts made regarding what is being asked. Maybe you should start by reading the docs about MailApp and GmailApp (tip GmailApp allows to use an alias as sender).

Comment: As stated very new to Appscript:

var useremail = response.getRespondentEmail();
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {from: useremail});

Comment: Lesson 1: Apps Script not Appscript

Comment: Regarding the code in your comment... What is the point including it? Do you tried to execute it? If so, does it works? if not, what error message did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get that you want to send emails on behalf of the form respondents. If that is correct, then there are two ways of doing it.

The most direct way is to keep using [`MailApp.sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) but specifying the respondent's email on the `replyTo` property (included in the method through the `options` parameter). With this approach you'll be indicating GitLab to answer back to the respondent's email.

If the previous technique doesn't suffice, then you should send the mail directly from the respondent Gmail account. Please, be aware that you can only run this operation if the user is in your domain. If that is true in your scenario, then you will have to activate [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation) for this procedure. Then you could use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role) to send the email on behalf of the user. Please, don't hesitate to ask me any doubts.

Comment: Thank you @Jacques-Guzel Heron , I ended up doing that and it worked.
Thanks for the input:

`var options2 = {
                 replyTo: useremail,
                 htmlBody: html,
                 attachments: file
                           };
  }
    
  
          
          GmailApp.sendEmail(email, ticketsubject,"", options2);`